# Displacement and Bump UV unwrap problem

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, displacement

I'm building a thick glass bottle in Blender 3.3.1 I'm using a displacement & bump to create an embossed effect on the glass surface. The issue is it's effecting the inside too.

Any idea's? Here's a screen grab of my shade editor & render.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Welcome, I want a slightly clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying, here is a clearer image[image: clearer image here]
I've done a bit more digging through tutorials and it's because I used a default UV map. I've since learnt to UnWrap a UV properly and the problem has solved itself. Thanks!